# Editing Sharepoint 2010 Asset Library View in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to make some changes to the Thumbnails view which is part of the Digital Assets Library in SharePoint 2010.  From the Library Ribbon I select "Modify View in SharePoint Designer".  After making the desired changes and saving when I then refresh the Library view from the site and I get an error on the page pointing me back to Sharepoint Designer.

When going back to SharePoint Designer the following error keeps appearing when it tries to reload the now customised XsltListViewWebPart it displays ...

**Web Part does not have a valid XSLT stylesheet: Error: End tag 'xsl:when' does not match the start tag 'xsl:value-of'**

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance, XML follows:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" Description="" PartOrder="2" Default="TRUE" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="False" IsIncludedFilter="" DataSourceID="" Title="Test Assets" ViewFlag="25165829" AllowConnect="True" DisplayName="Thumbnails" PageType="PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW" FrameState="Normal" PageSize="-1" PartImageLarge="" AsyncRefresh="False" ExportMode="NonSensitiveData" Dir="Default" DetailLink="/Test Assets" ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="83218135-042c-4c26-9ec8-b66337739345" ListName="{83218135-042C-4C26-9EC8-B66337739345}" FrameType="Default" PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" ViewGuid="{8A47238D-DA6C-42C0-B0F8-74BC97140455}" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ViewContentTypeId="0x" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" GhostedXslLink="AssetPicker.xsl" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." HelpMode="Modeless" ID="g_8a47238d_da6c_42c0_b0f8_74bc97140455" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True" TitleUrl="/Test Assets" ManualRefresh="False" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{8A47238D-DA6C-42C0-B0F8-74BC97140455}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
<ParameterBindings>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="Viewing" Location="Form(APDView)" DefaultValue="Thumbs" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="ThumbStyle" Location="Form(APDThumbNailStyle)" DefaultValue="medium" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
</ParameterBindings>
<XmlDefinition>
    <View Name="{8A47238D-DA6C-42C0-B0F8-74BC97140455}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="Thumbnails" Url="/Test Assets/Forms/Thumbnails.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="40" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png">
        <Query>
            <OrderBy>
                <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
            </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
            <FieldRef Name="ContentType"/>
            <FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus"/>
            <FieldRef Name="PreviewOnForm"/>
            <FieldRef Name="ThumbnailOnForm"/>
            <FieldRef Name="PublishingStartDate"/>
            <FieldRef Name="PublishingExpirationDate"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Editor"/>
        </ViewFields>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">20</RowLimit>
        <ViewStyle ID="0" DisplayName="Thumbnails"/>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
    </View>
</XmlDefinition>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<Xsl>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
        <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/AssetPicker.xsl"/>
        <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/internal.xsl"/>
        <xsl:param name="AllRows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[$EntityName = '' or (position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow)]"/>
        <xsl:param name="dvt_apos">&apos;</xsl:param>
        <xsl:template name="clientPageArray" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test ="$Picking='yes'">
                    <input type="hidden" name="assetpicking">
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Picking"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
                        <input type="hidden" name="webpartclientid" xsl:exclude-result-prefixes="SharePoint">
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$WebPartClientID"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
                            <input type="hidden" name="listid">
                                <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$List"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
                                <input type="hidden" name="thumbnailsize">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$ThumbnailSize"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="webimagewidth">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$WebImageWidth"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="webimageheight">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$WebImageHeight"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="canedit">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$CanEdit"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
                                                <script>
      if(&quot;function&quot; == typeof(AssetPickerPageCache)) g_AssetPickerPageCache = new AssetPickerPageCache();
      if(&quot;function&quot; == typeof(AssetPickerXslContext)) g_AssetPickerXslContext = new AssetPickerXslContext();
    </script>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <script type="text/javascript">
      var g_Rev = <xsl:value-of select="concat($squote,ddwrt:GetCurrentBuildVersion(),$squote)"/>;
      var g_AllowSilverlightPrompt = <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:AllowSilverlightPrompt()"/>;
      <![CDATA[
      var g_APD_ScriptsLoaded = 0;
      var g_APD_CsssLoaded = 0;
      function APD_CallbackWssView(who)
      {
        if(&quot;function&quot; == typeof(window.status)) window.status(&apos;Boot Strap Callback from &apos; + who);
      }
      function SmtAddWindowLoadEvent(handlerFunc)
      {
        if (window.attachEvent)
        {
            window.attachEvent(&quot;onload&quot;, handlerFunc);
        }
        else if (window.addEventListener)
        {
            window.addEventListener(&quot;load&quot;, handlerFunc, false);
        }
      }
      function APD_EnsureLoadHandlers()
      {
        EnsureScript(&quot;CMSSiteManager.js&quot;, typeof(AssetPickerPageCache), APD_LoadHandlers);
      }
      function APD_LoadHandlers()
      {
        g_AssetPickerPageCache = new AssetPickerPageCache();
        g_AssetPickerXslContext = new AssetPickerXslContext();
        EnsureScript(&quot;AssetPickers.js&quot;, typeof(AP_IsEmpty), APD_InitializeAssetPickerElements);
      }
      function APD_SimpleCacheControl()
      {
        return g_Rev;
      }
      function APD_AddStyleSheet(hrefValue)
      {
        if (!document.getElementsByTagName
        || !(document.createElement || document.createElementNS)) return;
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName(&quot;head&quot;)[0];
        var link = document.createElement(&quot;link&quot;);
        link.setAttribute(&apos;type&apos;, &apos;text/css&apos;);
        link.setAttribute(&apos;rel&apos;, &apos;stylesheet&apos;);
        link.setAttribute(&apos;media&apos;, &apos;screen&apos;);
        var rev = APD_SimpleCacheControl();
        var url = hrefValue + &quot;?rev=&quot;+rev;
        link.setAttribute(&apos;href&apos;, url);
        head.appendChild(link);
        return false;
      }
      function APD_AddScript(hrefValue)
      {
        if (!document.getElementsByTagName
        || !(document.createElement || document.createElementNS)) return;
        var loc = document.getElementsByTagName(&quot;head&quot;)[0];
        var rev = APD_SimpleCacheControl();
        var link = document.createElement(&quot;script&quot;);
        link.setAttribute(&apos;type&apos;, &apos;text/javascript&apos;);
        var url = hrefValue + &quot;?rev=&quot;+rev;
        link.setAttribute(&apos;src&apos;, url);
        loc.appendChild(link);
        link.onload = function () 
        {
          g_APD_ScriptsLoaded++;
          if(&quot;function&quot; == typeof(window.status)) window.status(&quot;Script #&quot; + g_APD_ScriptsLoaded + &quot; loaded&quot;);
        }
        return false;
      }
    ]]>
      if(document.g_APD_isFFScriptLoaded == undefined) 
      {
      APD_AddStyleSheet(<xsl:value-of select="concat($squote,$StylePath,'/portal.css',$squote)"/>);
      APD_AddScript(<xsl:value-of select="concat($squote,$LocScriptPath,'/CMSSiteManager.js',$squote)"/>);
      APD_AddScript(<xsl:value-of select="concat($squote,$LocScriptPath,'/AssetPickers.js',$squote)"/>);
      APD_AddScript(<xsl:value-of select="concat($squote,$NonLocScriptPath,'/MediaPlayer.js',$squote)"/>);
      SmtAddWindowLoadEvent(APD_EnsureLoadHandlers);
      document.g_APD_isFFScriptLoaded = true;
      }
    </script>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:template>
                                    <xsl:template mode="Item" match="Row[../../@BaseViewID='40']" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
                                        <xsl:param name="Fields" select="."/>
                                        <xsl:param name="Collapse" select="."/>
                                        <xsl:param name="Position" select="1"/>
                                        <xsl:param name="Last" select="1"/>
                                        <xsl:variable name="thisNode" select="."/>
                                        <xsl:variable name="imageId" select="concat('tiledimage_',$thisNode/@ID)"/>
                                        <li>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="$imageId"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:if test="$Collapse">
          <xsl:value-of select="$CBXStyle"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:attribute>
                                            <div>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="class">
          <xsl:value-of select="$StyleToApply"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:call-template name="RenderThumbnail">
                                                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                                                    <xsl:with-param name="subDir" select="'_t'"/>
                                                    <xsl:with-param name="resizeSquareSideLength" select="100"/>
                                                </xsl:call-template>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="class">ms-assetpicker-tiled-mediumprops</xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:call-template name="ItemData"/>
                                                <xsl:choose>
                                                    <xsl:when test="$Fields[@Name='Title']/following-sibling::FieldRef[@Name='LinkFilename']">
                                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$Fields[@Name='Title']" mode="PrintFieldWithECB">
                                                            <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                                                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                                                    </xsl:when>
                                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                                        <xsl:call-template name="LinkFilenameNoMenuAP">
                                                            <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                                                            <xsl:with-param name="ShowNonContainerLinkOnly" select="1"/>
                                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                                </xsl:choose>
                                            </div>
                                            <dl id="itemimages{generate-id()}">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="class">
          <xsl:value-of select="$StyleForHiding"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:for-each select="$Fields[not(@Name='ThumbnailOnForm') and not(@Name='PreviewOnForm') and not(@Name='DocIcon') and not(@Name='Title')]">
                                                    <dd>
                                                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Name,'_',$thisNode/@ID)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
                                                        <xsl:attribute name="class">
              <xsl:value-of select="$StyleForHiding"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
                                                        <span>
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="@DisplayName"/>
                                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="PrintFieldWithECB">
                                                                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode" />
                                                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </dd>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </dl>
                                        </li>
                                    </xsl:template>
                                    <xsl:template name="ItemData" mode="ClientData" match="Row" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
                                        <xsl:param name ="thisNode" select="."/>
                                        <xsl:variable name="imageId" select="concat('tiledimage_',$thisNode/@ID)"/>
                                        <input type="checkbox">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ID" /></xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="'ImageItem'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="iid">
          <xsl:value-of select="$ViewCounter"/>,<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ID" />,<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FSObjType" /></xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$Picking='yes'">
        <xsl:value-of select="$CBXStyle" />
    </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>display:inline;</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:call-template name="clientData">
                <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$imageId"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="canEdit">
                    <xsl:variable name="hasRight">
                        <xsl:call-template name="IfHasRight">
                            <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select ="$thisNode"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:value-of select="number($hasRight)"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="previewExists" select="$thisNode/@PreviewExists.value"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="thumbnailExists" select="$thisNode/@ThumbnailExists.value"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="alternateThumbnailUrl" select="$thisNode/@AlternateThumbnailUrl"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="parentId" select="$ParentId"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="propsUrl" select="concat($FORM_DISPLAY, '&amp;ID=',$thisNode/@ID)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name ="dwnlUrl" select ="concat($HttpVDir,'/_layouts/Download.aspx?SourceUrl=',$thisNode/@FileRef)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name ="editUrl" select ="concat($FORM_EDIT, '&amp;ID=',$thisNode/@ID)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name ="navUrl">
              <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileRef"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name ="imageHeight" select="$thisNode/@ImageHeight"/>
                <xsl:with-param name ="imageWidth" select="$thisNode/@ImageWidth"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="container">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@FSObjType='1'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="rootFolder">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@FSObjType='1'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileRef"/>
                </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="folderCTID">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@FSObjType='1'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ContentTypeId"/>
                </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name ="itemTitle">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@Title != ''">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Title"/>
                </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:call-template name="getFileName">
                                <xsl:with-param name="FileNameAndExt" select="$thisNode/@FileLeafRef"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name ="coutId_Loc" select="concat($thisNode/@CheckedOutUserId, '_', $thisNode/@IsCheckedoutToLocal)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name ="absUrl" select="concat($HttpHost,$thisNode/@FileRef)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
                                        </input>
                                    </xsl:template>
                                    <xsl:template match="FieldRef" name="LinkFilenameNoMenuAP" mode="Computed_LinkFilename_body" ddwrt:tag="a" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
                                        <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
                                        <xsl:param name="ShowAccessibleIcon" select="0"/>
                                        <xsl:param name="ShowNonContainerLinkOnly" select="0"/>
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="$Picking = 'yes' and $thisNode/@FSObjType != '1'">
                                                <a href="javascript:;">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileLeafRef.Name" />
                                                </a>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@FSObjType = '1' and ($Picking = 'yes' or $ShowNonContainerLinkOnly = '1')">
                                                <xsl:call-template name="LinkFilenameNoMenu">
                                                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                                                    <xsl:with-param name="ShowAccessibleIcon" select="$ShowAccessibleIcon"/>
                                                    <xsl:with-param name="IncludeOnClick">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$Picking = 'yes'">0</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:with-param>
                                                </xsl:call-template>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:choose>
                                                    <xsl:when test="$ShowNonContainerLinkOnly = '1'">
                                                        <a href="{$thisNode/@FileRef}">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Title" />
                                                        </a>
                                                    </xsl:when>
                                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                                        <xsl:call-template name="LinkFilenameNoMenu">
                                                            <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                                                            <xsl:with-param name="ShowAccessibleIcon" select="$ShowAccessibleIcon"/>
                                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                                </xsl:choose>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:template>
                                </xsl:stylesheet>
                            </Xsl>
                        </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

Comment: Help/pointers will follow if you at least post XSLT causing the problem.

Comment: @user574204: These kind of messages `"End tag 'xsl:when' does not match the start tag 'xsl:value-of'` are warnings about badformed XML. You possibly need to close the `xsl:value-of` instruction.

Comment: @Flack updated now with XSLT as requested thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should close your `input` literal elements like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="assetpicking">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Picking"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

In fact it's better to use AVT, when attribute name isn't calculated in run-time. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="assetpicking" value="{$Picking}"/>
```